# How to split a parameteric spline into two?

Tags: interpolation, curve, spline

I have a piece-wise parameteric Hermite cubic spline. For each piece of the spline the formula is:

```
Q = (2u^3-3u^2+1)p[i] + (-2u^3+3u^2)p[i+1] + (u^3-2u^2+u)tan[i] + (u^3-u^2)tan[i+1]
```

where u is the parameter for each piece is in [0,1] domain. Each p[i] is a control point and each tan[i] is the tangent of the curve on p[i]. Consider the following picture. I had three points and used natural end condition (Q" = 0) to solve tangents.

[image]

Now suppose we want to split the curve to two at some arbitrary position like on second piece where u = 0.2. The resulting curves should pass the same route but they should be independent like if I want to delete a piece I could and the other curve remain.

[image]

Comment: One thought would be to [convert it to Bezier form instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Representations), in which case splitting becomes almost trivial given the number of pages on the internet that explain how to do that.

Comment: (splitting information is easily googled for, but my own take on it is over on https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#splitting, or https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#matrixsplit if you're working in a matrix-optimized environment)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That's actually a very good idea. Thanks.